# Why does jupyter notebook on vscode always say not Python is installed?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Python is installed in Linux, as shown in terminal, but why does jupyter notebook on vscode always say not Python is installed?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Select python environment. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment

Comment: @YScharf  Thank you for your reply, but when I run any cell in jupyter notebook on vscode, why does it always say "install kernels from the marketplace"? Many thanks!

Comment: Can this help? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected a python environment which has jupyter notebook installed.

Install `jupyter` notebook in environment:

`pip install jupyter notebook`

Select environment in VSCode:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment